# How to ensure all kubernetes pods are zero in a deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I am having a kubernetes deployment. I am trying to scale down it to zero replicas. how will i wait to ensure the number pods are zero ?

the following is my command to scale down the deployment

```
kubectl scale deployment openet-k6 --replicas=0
```

How will i ensure all pods are scaled down ? I am actually using this command in a shell script , so i can write additional logic to check that .

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do a while loop, something like:

```
#! /bin/bash


while true; do
  kubectl get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[].status.phase' | grep 'Running'
  RC=$?

  if [ ${RC} -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "We're done here"
    exit 0
  fi

  sleep 3
done
```

The above is just a very simple example. Ideally, you'll want to filter your pods based on labels.